# Chrome LITE mode (android) keep my old VueJs app on clients (google server cache?)

Tags: android, google-chrome, vue.js, iis, caching

I am using IIS and my application is made with VueJs (SPA). I am already using cache busting, and no-cache configs on my web.config.

When updating my application, I made the web.config turn another index page as a default page (app_offline.htm), but when I tried to turn things back, mobile Chrome users got stucked on that updating page.

That only happens on LITE MODE Chrome Android.

Anyone has a solution for this?

---

Update 1

Even when I turn IIS offline my LITE mode Chrome continues show my old VueJS app (from google server?)

Update 2

I am getting that loading app on lite mode:

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 
Remote Address: 172.217.30.108:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: Hey @Paul did you find a resolution for this?